# Formatting a picture in Word using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Im working on making word documents from an Excel Sheet. In that regard i wanted to create a front page, consisting of the picture found in the Sheet "Forside". I want the picture to fill out the entire page, but have not been able to make it so. I have tried removing the margins, but every time it delete the margins in the entire document, instead of the first page only. Furthermore, I have tried to format the picture into Top and Bottom and then resize it without luck. I was hoping someone could help. I have posted to code beneath. (Im no expert, its my first time coding. So if you have some improvements feel free to write them)

```
Sub PrintAfWorddokument()
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim cht1 As ChartObject
    Dim cht2 As ChartObject
    Dim cht3 As ChartObject ' New chart object
    Dim wdRng As Word.Range
    Dim rngA25 As Range
    Dim pic As Shape ' New picture shape
    Dim img As Object

    
    ' Create a new instance of Word and make it visible
    Set wdApp = New Word.Application
    wdApp.Visible = True
    
    ' Activate Word
    wdApp.Activate
    
    ' Create a new Word document
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add
       
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Forside")
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set img = ws.Shapes("Picture 1")
    
    If img Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Picture not found in the 'Forside' sheet.", vbExclamation
        wdDoc.Close False
        wdApp.Quit
        Set wdDoc = Nothing
        Set wdApp = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    img.Copy
    
    wdApp.Selection.Paste

    
    ' Paste data from cell A1:A21
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Til Word Dokument")
    ws.Range("A1:A21").Copy
    wdApp.Selection.Paste
    
    ' Copy the charts
    Set cht1 = ws.ChartObjects("Chart1")
    Set cht2 = ws.ChartObjects("Chart2")
    
    ' Add a new page for the charts
    wdDoc.Sections.Add
    
    ' Insert the text "Formue oversigt" above the charts with formatting
    Set wdRng = wdDoc.Sections(wdDoc.Sections.Count).Range
    wdRng.Text = "Formue oversigt"
    wdRng.Font.Name = "Calibri"
    wdRng.Font.Size = 20
    wdRng.Font.Bold = True
    wdRng.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
    wdRng.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    wdRng.InsertParagraphAfter
    
    ' Set the width and height of both charts (adjust as needed)
    cht1.Width = InchesToPoints(3) ' Adjust as needed
    cht1.Height = InchesToPoints(3) ' Adjust as needed
    cht2.Width = InchesToPoints(3) ' Adjust as needed
    cht2.Height = InchesToPoints(3) ' Adjust as needed

    ' Insert the first chart
    wdRng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    cht1.Copy
    wdRng.Paste
    wdRng.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    
    ' Insert the second chart beside the first chart
    cht2.Copy
    wdRng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    wdRng.Paste
    wdRng.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    
       ' Insert a paragraph break after the new chart
    wdRng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    wdRng.InsertParagraphAfter
    
        ' Set the range for cell A25
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Til Word Dokument") ' Switch back to the original worksheet
    Set rngA25 = ws.Range("A25")
    
    ' Copy cell A25 with the same formatting as "Formue oversigt"
    rngA25.Copy
    wdRng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    wdRng.Paste
    wdRng.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    
    ' Insert a paragraph break to separate the charts from the text
    wdRng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    wdRng.InsertParagraphAfter
    
    ' Insert the text "Chart from Beregning (optimal)" on a new page
    wdDoc.Sections.Add
    Set wdRng = wdDoc.Sections(wdDoc.Sections.Count).Range
    wdRng.Text = "Formue udvikling"
    wdRng.Font.Name = "Calibri"
    wdRng.Font.Size = 20
    wdRng.Font.Bold = True
    wdRng.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
    wdRng.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    wdRng.InsertParagraphAfter
    
    ' Set the new width and height of the chart (adjust as needed)
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Beregning (optimal)") ' Use the correct worksheet name
    Set cht3 = ws.ChartObjects("Chart 1") ' Change to the correct chart name
    cht3.Width = InchesToPoints(7) ' Adjust as needed
    cht3.Height = InchesToPoints(6) ' Adjust as needed
    
    ' Insert the new chart
    cht3.Copy
    wdRng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    wdRng.Paste
    wdRng.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    
End Sub
```

It states in the description of the problem

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: To change the margins on only one page, you need to use section breaks. Look at Method 2 on [this web site](https://officebeginner.com/msword/how-to-change-margin-on-one-page-in-ms-word/)

Comment: fyi - not an answer. `On Error GoTo 0` just before `If img Is Nothing Then` otherwise the error bypass remains in effect.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 different ways to place something like a picture (general speaking, "shapes") on a word document: As *inline shape* and as *shape*. An inline shape flows with the text: If you add something before the image, the image moves down with the text. A (non-inline) shape can be formatted using the layout button so that for example text flows around it, or that the text is printed above or below the image.

When you paste an image into Word, it will be pasted as inline shape. As inline shapes flow with the text, they also respect the page margins and you cannot make them bigger than the area where the text is located (you can't place them on the page margins). Your only option would be to define an own section for the page that holds the image, having margins = 0.

A (non-inline) shape can be resized to whatever size you want. All you have to do is convert the inline shape to a shape - that's easy, just use the `ConvertToShape`-method. After that, it's easy to set the size of that shape.

The following snippet will convert the first inline shape into a shape and resize it to full screen. After that, it will add a page break so that the following content is not put onto the same page.

```
' (your code): 
img.Copy
wdApp.Selection.Paste

' Get shape object. If inline shape, convert it to shape
If wdDoc.InlineShapes.Count > 0 Then 
    Dim sh As Shape
    Set sh = wdDoc.InlineShapes(1).ConvertToShape
    ' Shape fullsize
    With wdDoc.PageSetup
        sh.Left = -.LeftMargin
        sh.Width = .PageWidth
        sh.Top = -.TopMargin
        sh.Height = .PageHeight
    End With

    ' Add a space and a Pagebreak to continue on the next page
    wdApp.Selection.TypeText Text:=" "
    wdApp.Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
End If
```